# Get count of matches using regex in Hive?

Tags: regex, hive

I want to get the count value from a table based on regex matching.
For example, say I want to find all strings in my table that end with
"/top" and the table contains the following data:

```
id  url
1   example.com/top
2   example.com/index.html
3   example2.com/top
```

The following query seems to hit every row, instead of just two:

```
  select
  sum(CASE WHEN url REGEXP '.*/top' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as topCount,
  sum(CASE WHEN url REGEXP '.*/index.html' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as defaultCount
  from myTable
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the condition in `where`.

```
select count(*) from myTable where url REGEXP '.*/top$'
```

Comment: Thx. My version was a bit too simplified though so I added another column that I'm trying to get.